The third option in my if function is not working
The third option in the if function in the code below does not work. How do I get it to work?
I've tried changing the last "else if" to just else, but it does not work either.
I am new to coding and cannot understand why it isn't working.
#include<iostream>

int main () {
    auto x = int{100};
    auto y = int{0};
    auto z = int{3};

    label:
    while (z > 0) {
        std::cerr << "Enter a pair of integers: ";
        label2:
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cin >> y;    
        if (x > y){
            std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
            goto label2;
        }
        else if (x = y) {
            goto label2;
        }
        else if (x < y) {
            std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
            z = z - 1;
            goto label;
        };
        }
    return 0;
}

EDIT: As per the comments, I am expecting to input a pair of integers and have one of three things happen:

If the x integer is greater than the y integer, I expect the program to output what was entered and loop back to the label "label".

If the x integer is equal to the y integer, I expect the program to allow input of integers again with no output to the user.

If the x integer is less than the y integer, I expect the program to output what was entered, decrease the value of z and loop back to the label "label"


*The z integer is being used as a way to exit the code after three inputs of an x integer less than the y integer.
**When compiling with the -Wall command I get a compiler warning suggesting an extra pair of parentheses around the '(x = Y)' portion of the code. Adding the parentheses does not change the issue but has been done as I assume it is best practice.
EDIT2: If I switch the position of the '((x=y))' else if portion and the '(x < y)' else if portion the code executes as I intended.
For those asking why I am using label and goto, I do not know another way to do what I am intending. Again I am very new to coding (as in my first week of trying coding).
I apologize for asking questions that probably have very easy answers, but I am just trying to learn. Hopefully, one day I will be better at coding and can assist others with questions they may have.

What do you mean by "it doesn't work?" Please [edit] your question to include the desired behavior and actual behavior of this program, likely with some instructions on what to input when running it.

Take one more look at the condition x = y. How does it differ from other = usages in your code? Enable compiler warnings -Wall.

https://xkcd.com/292/

Go To Statement Considered Harmful.

@wohlstad This is a silly generalization. For "error, try again" cases like here, goto is a very suitable tool.

why are you using std::cerr and goto

@j6t "For "error, try again" cases like here, goto is a very suitable" - I disagree, but I guess it's a matter of opinion. In any case the link I shared is a classic and I thought it is worth mentioning.

Read the error message again and in greater detail: " warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]" That is, use parentheses to make it clear that you want an assignment here and not a comparison which would be more usual in this context - presuming that is truly what you want.

Can you explain what x = int{100} does? After you explain that, can you explain what x = y does?

if (x = y) is assigning the value of y to x and then comparing only the value of x for non-zero. That is not the correct behavior you want. You need to use == instead to compare the values of x and y against each other: if (x == y)

x = y should be x == y.  goto label2 could be replaced with continue , goto label is redundant

Back to the drawing board for you, NEVER use goto in a C++ program

@AviBerger and the others explaining the assign values versus compare values, Thank you! I did not know that this was a thing. I appreciate the knowledge you've imparted and won't make this mistake again.

@3CxEZiVlQ x = int{100} assigns x the value of 100 as an integer. I now understand that what I wanted to do was x == y to compare values. I should have guessed that the same thing could not do two different functions. Thank you for your help!


you are using = instead of ==, = is assign, and == is compare.
As @biffen and @wohlstad's comment pointed out, try not to use goto statement, it is not good practices and make the code hard to reason, xkcd, restructure your control flow to avoid goto
why are you using std::cerr, it is not suppose to be an error, so I think you should use std::cout.
if you want to repeat something a certain number of time (here z times), use a for loop instead of a while loop.
(opinion) x and y should be scoped, inside the loop to make your code easier to follow
(opinion) try avoid repeating, extract the print statement.

#include<iostream>

int main () {
    auto z = int{3};

    for (int i = 0; i < z ; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter a pair of integers: ";
        
        auto x = 100;
        auto y = 0;
        
        while (x >= y) {
            std::cin >> x >> y;
            
            if (x != y) 
                std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Output
Enter a pair of integers: 1 2
You entered 1 and 2
Enter a pair of integers: 2 2
2 1
You entered 2 and 1
1 2
You entered 1 and 2
Enter a pair of integers: 2 1
You entered 2 and 1
1 1
1 2
You entered 1 and 2


The code below resolves the issue I was having but do not understand why.
#include<iostream>

int main () {
auto x = int{100};
auto y = int{0};
auto z = int{3};

label:
while (z > 0) {
    std::cerr << "Enter a pair of integers: ";
    label2:
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cin >> y;    
    if (x > y) {
        std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
        goto label2;
    }
    else if (x < y) {
        std::cout << "You entered " << x << " and " << y << "\n";
        z = z - 1;
        goto label;
    }
    else if ((x = y)) {
        goto label2;
    };
    }
return 0;
}


Now enter 0 0 and your new code does not work.
